# React - Keep newly added key & value in object after re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add a "sorting" system to a clothing website I am building. The issue I am having is that whenever a new parameter is being added, it removes the old one added. I would guess the reason is that the variable holding the parameters are being re-rendered whenever you sort the products.

Here is my code:

```
const FetchAPI = (props) => {
  const [product, setProducts] = useState([]);
  // Key and Value
  let facetKey = props.facetKey;
  let facetValue = props.facetValue;

  let params = {
    store: "US",
    offset: props.offset,
    categoryId: props.categoryId,
    limit: props.limit,
    country: "US",
    sort: "freshness",
    currency: "USD",
    sizeSchema: "US",
    lang: "en-US",
  };

  if (facetKey) {
    params = { ...params, offset: 0, limit: 0, [facetKey]: facetValue };
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://asos2.p.rapidapi.com/products/v2/list",
      params: params,
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-key": "",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "",
      },
    };

    axios
      .request(options)
      .then(function (response) {
        setProducts(response.data.products);
        props.items(response.data.itemCount);
        props.facets(response.data.facets);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, [props.limit, facetValue]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.container}>
        {product.map((product) => (
          <ProductCard
            key={product.id}
            img={product.imageUrl}
            name={product.name}
            price={product.price.current.text}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The re-rendering of `params` occurs because it is inside of the `const FetchAPI`, but I am not that sure how I can "ignore" that and make the `params` keep the first value. Perhaps could I solve this by putting the values in localstorage? Or is there a better way?

Comment: According to your logic, after first render `if(facetKey)` is always true therefore it will reset the params as expected.

Comment: yea, but shouldn't add back the params as it has a spread operator? `{...params, // etc}` @DennisVash

Comment: But you override it with new params after... `{...params, ...otherArgsOverrideIt}`

Comment: @DennisVash ohh! I see what you mean, the `...params` were supposed to come after! Thank you  :)

Comment: Or actually, no. That did not work. @DennisVash

Comment: I didn't say it will work, I said thats what your code logic is saying, you might to change it, for example move the condition into the useEffect, cant suggest more then that without reproducible example

Comment: @DennisVash ah okay, I see. Well, I'll try to figure something out here on my end! :)

Comment: Everything seems OK in code. I think you should use the useState for handling params and sorting params.
Then use the same logic with state

Comment: @VikashDhiman ah yeah, I tried that by setting a new useState that holds the `params`. The initial state being `store: "us", offset: props.offset` etc etc. Then inside of my useEffect I put the `setParams({...params, [facetKey]: facetValue})`. Does not seem to work tho, posted this on pastebin as well: `C8iGD6uU`. These sort of things always has me confused! haha